# How to parallelize str.split in Polars

Tags: python-polars

Let's say I have a dataframe with a comma-separated column called `tags` and I want to split them by commas using Polars:

```py
df = pl.read_ipc("items.fth")
tags_df = df.select(pl.col("tags").str.split(","))
```

The dataframe is in uncompressed feather format, so it can be mapped in memory and it has over 10M rows, if any of this matters.

The above code works, but it's only using 1 CPU. How can it make it use all available CPUs?

Answer (score 0):

You could load the file into multiple LazyFrames for each core you have then concat them together.

For instance:

```
from math import ceil
df = pl.read_ipc("items.fth")
cores = 10 #change this to fit your system
height = df.height
rows_at_a_time = ceil(height/cores)
tags_df = pl.concat(df.slice(x*rows_at_a_time, rows_at_a_time).lazy()
            .select(pl.col("tags").str.split(",")) for x in range(cores)).collect()
```

Disclaimer: I'm a bit skeptical that parallelism will speed up a `str.split` operation relative to the overhead of actually parallelizing it.

As an aside, you could try making the df initialize as lazy via `scan_ipc` instead of having the call to `lazy()` after the slice. At some point though you have to make them lazy for concat to parallelize them.